# Difficulty with conditional databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, binding, conditional-statements

I've been struggling to find some way to do my required conditional binding.

I want to use `Eval("products_image")` in conditional binding in such a way that if product_image exists in images directory then it's ok, otherwise it should display "noimage.jpg".

I tried to do it this way:

```
<%# (File.Exists(("ProductImages/"+Convert.ToString(Eval("products_image"))))) ? ("ProductImages/"+Convert.ToString(Eval("products_image"))) : "ProductImages/noimage_small.jpg" ; %>
```

I have tried other ways as well, but every time, I mess up with a bunch of errors.

Can anyone guide me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# (File.Exists(("ProductImages/"+Convert.ToString(Eval("products_image"))))) ? ("ProductImages/"+Convert.ToString(Eval("products_image"))) : "ProductImages/noimage_small.jpg" ; %>
```

Quite long and unreadable, isn't it?

I'd suggest adding a method to your code behind or in a `<script>` tag

```
// returns the imageFile parameter if the file exists, the defaultFile parameter otherwise
string ImageFileExists(string imageFile, string defaultFile) {
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(imageFile)))
        return imageFile;
    else
        return defaultFile;
}
```

And then you'd simply use

```
<%# ImageFileExists("ProductImages/" + Eval("products_image").ToString(), "ProductImages/noimage_small.jpg") %>
```

Note that I've added a [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) call to the method so that `File.Exists` will actually look in the right place.

Comment: +1: Crap, you beat me to it. And with a pretty neat solution too. :)

Comment: yeah this is great. i have added ImageFileExists method in <script  type="text/C#"> tag inside my masterpage. then i have put <%# ImageFileExists("Pr .... into a UserControl Productlist.ascx file, where it was required. (Note that, this .ascx file is then included in a page that is holding that masterpage).

but when i run it, it says: 
error CS0103: The name 'ImageFileExists' does not exist in the current context

whats solution :(

Comment: I think you're missing a runat="server" in your script tag... Did you put one in?

Comment: yes it was missing, i have put it there. but it is still errrroring. CS0103: The name 'ImageFileExists' does not exist in the current context. is there some different way to use it inside a .ascx file?

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the whole `<script>` tag and `System.IO` namespace inside the usercontrol .ascx file itself and it did it.

Thanks a ton **configurator** for help :)